# I am using react-router-dom for my react.js project and it adds /#/ in the route URL. Can I get rid of it? if yes, how?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am using Switch and Route from react-router-dom in my reactJS project. And it automatically adds # at the end of the route URLs.
example, if I navigate to `localhost:3000` it will show the URL as `localhost:3000/#/ .` 
I want to get rid of this # as I am developing a customer facing product and don't want my URLs to have # in it.
Is there any way for removing that "`#`"?Help is much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Edit:

```
import { Switch, Route, withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
@inject('userStore', 'commonStore', 'authStore')
@withRouter
@observer
export default class App extends React.Component {
render(){
return(
 <Switch >
<Route path="/signin" component={Login} />
</Switch >
)


}
}
```

Comment: What version of `react-router-dom` are you using?

Comment: I am using version 4.3.1

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are using a `HashRouter` component. If you replace this with the `BrowserRouter` component you will get normal URLs.

Adding the code from your root `app.js` file to your question will help us debug further.

Edit:

Since you aren't specifying a router component, it `react-router` is defaulting to `HashRouter`. You need to wrap your whole app component in a `BrowserRouter` component to get good urls:

```
import { Switch, Route, BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

render(){
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch >
        <Route path="/signin" component={Login} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response,I have added the sample code as edit in the question.

Comment: Updated my answer with how to add `BrowserRouter`

Comment: I updated my code as per your suggestions, however it is still adding # to my URLs.
I am actually specifying the router as "withRouter", I removed that from the code thinking it was irrelevent. Let me update the question again. 
I am injecting it to the component.